# Defining and exporting HOC in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, higher-order-components

I've been research Higher Order Components in react. My requirement is that I have a set components which I need to extend to give them more functionality without rewriting the entire component. In this case, I found out the concept HOC in react where one could extend the component using a pure function. My question is, can I export the extended component as a normal component. For an example

**Component which needs to be extended**

```
class foo extends React.Component {
    render(){
        //something
    }
}

export default foo;
```

**HOC component**

```
function bar(foo) {
    render() {
         return <foo {...this.props} {...this.state} />;
    }
}

export default bar;
```

Am I able to use the component that way? or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A HOC would take a component, add some more functionality and return a new component and not just return the component instance,

What you would do is

```
function bar(Foo) {

   return class NewComponent extend React.Component {
        //some added functionalities here
        render() {
            return <Foo {...this.props} {...otherAttributes} />
        }
   }

}

export default bar;
```

Now when you want to add some functionality to a component you would create a instance of the component like

```
const NewFoo = bar(Foo);
```

which you could now use like

```
return (
    <NewFoo {...somePropsHere} />
)
```

Additionally you could allow the HOC to take a default component and export that as a default component and use it elsewhere like

```
function bar(Foo = MyComponent) {
```

and then create an export like

```
const wrapMyComponent = Foo();
export { wrapMyComponent as MyComponent };
```

A typical use-case of an HOC could be a `HandleClickOutside` functionality whereby you would pass a component that needs to take an action based on `handleClickOutside` functionality

Comment: great answer. One question though. Is it possible to write HOC components that could directly render without creating an instance.

Comment: @ImeshChandrasiri In that case it would not be an HOC, rather a component that renders another component, However you could just default export some component wrapped with HOC, the HOC and always take a default component and return it

Comment: Shouldn't `const wrapMyComponent = Foo();` be `const wrapMyComponent = bar();` ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be like this:

Make a Foo Component

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return ( < h1 > hello I am in Foo < /h1>)
      }
    }
```

Make a HOC component.

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const {
      component, props
    } = this.props;
    //extract the dynamic component passed via props.
    var Component = component;

    return ( < div > 
          < h1 > I am in main < /h1> 
          < Component {...props} > < /Component>
          </div > );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render( < Main component = {
    Foo
  } > < /Main>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZLX4nysSphEq188l29YL?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```
const bar = (Foo) => {
   return class MyComponent extend Component {
        render() {
            return <Foo {...this.props} />
        }
   }
}
```

//Our Foo Component Code Here

```
export default bar(Foo)
```

But again it depends on the functionality. Eg: suppose you're using react router and want to check if user is present before rendering the component don't pass the HOC. eg:

```
<Route path="/baz" component={auth(Foo)} />
```

Instead use an new component.

Note: NewComponent is connected to redux and user (state) is passed as props

```
class NewRoute extends Component{
    render(){
        const {component:Component, ...otherProps} = this.props;

        return(
          <Route render={props => (
            this.props.user? (
              <Component {...otherProps} /> 
              ):(
              <Redirect  to="/" />
                )
            )} 
          />
        );
    }
}
```

Then on the routes

```
<NewRoute path='/foo' component={Foo} />
```