# React Higher Order Component without input component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I would like to know whether or not it makes sense to have a "higher order components" without an actual component as input but still returning a component.

Following use case:
I need to implement an UI-Kit including a bunch of (custom) input fields which are all pretty much the same in style and only different in type, error message and a few other small things.
Each of these input fields consists of 2 parent div's and the actual html input element.

Since I've never seen something like this (my idea of doing), I'd like to know whether or not my approach is anywhere near the real world.

I have an higher order component or higher order *layout*:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

export default handler => staticProps =>
  class extends PureComponent {
    render() {
      return (
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={handler.onChange}
          placeholder={staticProps.placeholder} />
      );
    }
  };
```

And a place where I use give my component the props that it should use:

```
import Hoc from './HocTextInput';

const handler = {
  onChange: e => console.log(e.target.value),
};

const staticProps = {
  placeholder: 'Placeholder',
};

export default Hoc(handler)(staticProps);
```

My idea is to not repeat myself when using composition etc. 
But like I already mentioned, I'm not sure whether I should do it like this.

**Is this bad practice? If so, can you give me an alternative solution?**

Comment: do you want to have custom components instead of inputs??

Comment: this was just example code.. but in my case I have (almost) always the same layout (2 nested div's and and an input element). Only the handler and a few messages will change.

Answer (score 0):

If your Layout is the same and you need not add any specific functionality to your components, you might as well make use of props instead of writing a higher order component

```
  class App extends PureComponent {
    render() {
      const {handler, staticProps} = this.props;
      return (
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={handler.onChange}
          placeholder={staticProps.placeholder} />
      );
    }
  };
```

and use it like

```
const handler = {
   onChange: this.onChange
}
const staticProps = {
   foo: 'bar'
}
<App handler={handler} staticProps={staticProps} />
```

HOCs will come in handle when in a layout you need to add replace some specific component or you wish to add certain functionality to your components like handling outside click

Comment: You might check this answer  too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47527931/defining-and-exporting-hoc-in-react/47528061#47528061

Comment: but then i couldn't "curry" it right? That's the main reason why I want to do it.

Comment: We aren't writing a HOC in this case so no need of currying